# How can I absolutely orient text in SVG

Tags: jquery, text, svg, orientation

I have an SVG containing several groups of elements, one image grouping has `<text>` nodes surrounding it.

I am using jQuery to `clone()` and add `rotate(a)` this group so that the path appears several times around a shape.  When I rotate the whole group, the text orientation changes with the angle of the rotation.  I could alternatively draw separate paths, but then if I want to make changes ot the shape of the path I need propagate those changes, including recalculation of coordinates etc.

Instead, I want the text to be in the same relative position in the rotated image, but oriented vertically.

Is there a `<g>` or `<text>` property I can set to absolutely determine text orientation as left to right?  If not, then is there a better way to get the end result I want?

```
//Just in case this isn't blatantly obvious, this is just a mock up.  You may correct any syntax errors you find, but they are NOT the source of any trouble.
var svg = $('#container');
var group = $(document.createElementNS(svgns,'g'));

group.attr('id','groupA');
var path = $(document.createElementNS(svgns,'path');
path.attr('d', 'M40 40 A9,2 0 0,1 100 40'); //A simple arc
group.append(path);

var text = $(document.createElementNS(svgns,'text') ;
text.attr('class','someclass');
group.append(text);

svg.append(group);
group=group.clone();
group.attr('id','groupB');
group.attr('transform','rotate(90, 100, 100)'); //rotates both path and text around the center of image.  I'd rather keep text upright, although I want it in the same relative position
svg.append(group)
```

Comment: I'm finding this difficult to visualize. Could you link to a reduced example?

Comment: Can't link, but I'll mock something up in the question

Comment: Thanks for the code. Unfortunately, it's still not clear to me what the goal would look like. Specifically, what you mean by "text to be in the same relative position in the rotated image, but oriented vertically". Maybe you could just draw it and post it to an photo sharing site?

Comment: The text is rotated with the image.  I want to have not rotated text.  I want it in the same place.

Comment: Why not simply not rotate the image, as opposed to rotating the group containing both the image and the text?

Comment: Well I want the text to move with the image.  I just don't want the text to turn sideways.

Comment: So you want to translate the text, but not rotate it? And you want to translate the text such that the upper left corner of its bounding box is the same as the upper left corner of the bounding box of the rotated image?

Comment: That sounds right.  I was hoping there was a property of <text> that would allow me to say "orient text direction based on the top level container".  If you could show me how to do calculate translation such that it will work for any angle of rotation, that would work.

Comment: Or of course, any better idea to achieve the same effect

Comment: Yah, I think you would need to do this in script. I've been trying to think if there's a way to do it without using getBBox, just using the properties of the rotation transformation, but I don't think there's a cleaner way to do it. I'll put my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should only rotate the image, not the group containing the text and the image.

Second, using the `getBBoxInElementSpace` and `getBoundingBoxInArbitrarySpace` functions from [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/sandbox/gsoc/2010/scxml-js/trunk/src/javascript/scxml/cgf/util/svg.js), get the bounding box of the rotated image using the following call:

`var imageBBox = getBBoxInElementSpace(text,image);`

Then update the text position as follows:

`text.x.baseVal.getItem(0).value = imageBBox.x;
text.y.baseVal.getItem(0).value = imageBBox.y;`