# Convert SVG Rect x,y to screen left and top jQuery SVG

Tags: jquery, svg, position, google-visualization

I am using Google visualization to generate some column chart, to spice the display I want to change the annotation using some custom text and image, to do this I need to get the exact top and left position of each annotation

Currently I am just applying some random values after a series of trial and error to make the layout close to what I am looking for

I would like to know whether its possible to convert x,y values of annotation to screen left and top values, that way I will be able to get the desired layout.

Please see this link 
http://www.screencast.com/t/f0ytn2m0IS

The small orange icons with values like 230 etc are the ones which should be in line to the line graph

Comment: You can check this article "SVG Coordinate Transformations" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh535760(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer "[How can I absolutely orient text in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993570/how-can-i-absolutely-orient-text-in-svg/6049080#6049080)". You can create jQuery plugin using [code from that answer](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/sandbox/gsoc/2010/scxml-js/trunk/src/javascript/scxml/cgf/util/svg.js).

```
$.fn.getRealBBox = function() {
    if (this[0] instanceof SVGElement) {
        return getBoundingBoxInArbitrarySpace(this[0], this[0].getCTM());
    } else {
        throw "selector '" + this.selector + "' is not SVGElement";
    }
};
```

and use it to get x and y, then you can set the object top an left to those values, if you want the html object to be in the middle just add `box.width/2` and `box.height/2`.